# Is it Possible to have If statement where something is not present?

Tags: python, if-statement, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape a dynamic loading page and do not want to use selenium so instead I am attempting to use data-price_excl_tax, which is where I am getting the pricing for the table, (see below) as a means to return the qty. I am attempting to do this through if statements where:

**if data-price_excl_tax_5 is present then data-price_excl_tax_4 = 4

but if data-price_excl_tax_5 is not present then data-price_excl_tax_4 = 4-5

I also need:

if data-price_excel_12 is present then data-price_excl_tax_6 = 6-11

but if it is not present then data-price_excl_tax = 6+**

Any help would be greatly appreciated

HTML Code

```
<form id="cart-30102" action="/cart/add/" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-add_savings_message="true" data-price_excl_tax="38.99" data-price_excl_tax_2="24.87" data-price_excl_tax_3="22.99" data-price_excl_tax_4="23.89" data-price_excl_tax_5="23.04" data-price_excl_tax_6="22.19" data-price_excl_tax_12="21.86">
```

example url: https://filterbuy.com/brand/trion-air-bear-air-filters/20x20x5-air-bear-20x20/?selected_merv=11

This is my python code:

```
from web_sites import web_sites
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

PATH = '***'

urls = web_sites

#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver.get(urls)



for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

mervs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml').find_all('strong')
product = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml').find("h1", class_="text-center")
product_name = product.text
qty="something in (data-price_excl_tax)"
json_schema = soup.find_all('script', attrs={'type': 'application/ld+json'})[1]
json_file = json.loads(json_schema.get_text())
the_dict = json_file
n = the_dict['@graph'][0]
descriptions = n['description']
d = the_dict['@graph'][0]['aggregateRating']
ratingValue = d['ratingValue']
reviewCount = d['reviewCount']


for i, cart in enumerate(BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml').find_all('form', class_='cart')):
    for tax in cart.attrs:
        if 'data-price' in tax:
            if 'data-price_excl_tax' in tax:
                qty= '1'
                if 'data-price_excl_tax_2' in tax:
                    qty= '2'
                if 'data-price_excl_tax_3' in tax:
                    qty= '3'
                #if ('data-price_excl_tax_4' and 'data-price_excl_tax_5') in tax:
                    #qty= "4"
                #if  ('data-price_excl_tax_5') in tax:
                    #qty= "4-5"
                if 'data-price_excl_tax_5' in tax:
                    qty="5"
                #if 'data-price_excl_tax_6' and 'data-price_excl_tax_12' in tax:
                    #qty="6-11"
                #if 'data-price_excl_tax_6' in tax:
                    #qty="6+"
                if 'data-price_excl_tax_12' in tax:
                    qty="12+"

            print(product_name.replace("\n", "").replace("('", "").strip(), mervs[i].get_text(), qty, cart[tax], ratingValue, reviewCount)
            #header = ['merv', 'price', 'json_file']
            data = [product_name.replace("\n", "").replace("('", "").strip(), mervs[i].get_text(), qty, cart[tax],ratingValue,reviewCount]
            with open('products1.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='UTF8') as csv_file:
                writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter =',')
                #writer.writerow(header)
                writer.writerow(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be [find()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree) method will be usefull?

```py
for i, cart in enumerate(BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml').find_all('form', class_='cart')):
    for tax in cart.attrs:
        if  in tax.find('data-price'):
             print('found')
```